# joins in a mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm new to stored procedures, and I am not sure how to do this - I have a complicated set of mysql commands, creating temporary tables, joins, etc. They operate on existing tables, and there are many possible sets of existing tables that I might want to do this with. As a trivial example I might want to say "select * from t1 join t2", but I would like a procedure that accepts various t1 and t2 as arguments. Apparently stored procedures don't accept tables as arguments, so I'm wondering what the way to do this would be. Thanks for any help.

Comment: hmm this sound like you need prepared statement, but I'm not quiet sure what exactly you want to do. If you want to pass your procedure two table names (t1 and t2) and use them in your select query then that can be done with prepared statement..

Comment: Here is small [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ffbc9/1) so you can see what I mean under prepared statement. This is small example where you pass only one table name but it's pretty much the same on large scale. but the answer really depends on your database structure and how that table are correlated...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a prepared statement like this:

```
    set @query = concat("select * from ", table_name_param1,
      " t1 left join ", table_name_param2, " t2 on t1.id = t2.id" );
     prepare s from @query;
     execute s;
```

Comment: H Sasha - yes, thats the kind of thing I need, thank you. I tried it and it worked, the only problem is that I have 4 statements. Looking at "execute" syntax, I see I cannot concatenate statements into a single statment. Do you know of any way to shorten the process other than four executes?

Comment: You do a separate prepare/execute for each statement. If that does not answer it, post a specific example.

Comment: Hi Sasha - that works fine, I was just wondering if there was any better way. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Based on the question, this is the way. Please mark as Answered with the Green check mark under the up and down arrows unless you disagree (I sure don't).